# Call Function inside of another class that is threaded

Tags: multithreading, wxpython

I am writing a gui application in python.  In one instance of the GUI I want to call a method inside of my thread class, but I don't want to call the initial run() method.

Here is an example of my Threaded class:

```
class SomeThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        self.queue = queue
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def SomeMethod():
        print "success"

    def run(self):
        apple = "eat a apple"

        self.queue.put(apple) # pass var into queue
```

I attempt to call the SomeMethod here

```
class SomeGUIClass(wx.Frame):

    def MethodA(self,event):
            SomeThread.SomeMethod()
```

But I get an error that states "type object 'SomeThread' has no attribute 'SomeMethod'.  How can I call this SomeMethod function directly without executing the run(self) method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the text editor had some trouble with the tabs/spacing of certain elements.  I got it to work after fixing the indentation by calling:

```
self.queue = Queue.Queue()
SomeThread(self.queue).SomeMethod()
```